# can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Tags: html, css

[why is it happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkobk.png)

I created a  inside a link, to make the div link's child, but I don't know why the parent link is appearing inside the div. I am new to html/css, please help me. and tell what are things I should know to not make those mistakes

here is my code

https://codepen.io/Poink/pen/OJwJdrP

```
<a class="AB" href="https://zoro.to/steinsgate-3?ref=search">
<div class="Queen">
    <div class="a">Steins Gate</div>
    <div class="b"><span style="color: rgb(168, 164, 164);">⭐9.09</span></div>
    <div class="c"><span style="color: rgb(168, 164, 164);">Ep24/24</span></div>
    <div class="ac"></div>
    <div class="d"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">TV</span></div>
    <div class="e">
        <span style="color: rgb(168, 164, 164);">
            The self-proclaimed mad scientist Rintarou
            Okabe rents out a room in a rickety old building in 
            Akihabara, where he indulges...
        </span>
    
    
    </div>
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve with the link and the div?

Comment: You're still in the <a> link when you're declaring the rest of it, so it's all a hyperlink. You need to </a> to close the link

Comment: when I hover over link, i wanted the div to show up, it was all working until, i started to style the div

Comment: Guy s, i closed the link, you can go to the code link check, sorry

Comment: Post all the relevant code in the question. You can use the `<>` button to create a runnable snippet. No need for an external site.

Comment: please read about good questions on stack overflow and use more specific titles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not closing all div, that is why displaying link into div

```
<body>
    
    
<div class="King">
<div class="A"></div>
<div class="ab">Steins Gate</div>
<div class="B"></div>
<div class="C">SUB</div>
<div class="D">DUB</div>
<div class="E">Ep24/24</div>
<div class="F">Steins Gate</div>
<div class="G"> <span style="color: gray;">TV</span></div>
<div class="H"></div>
<div class="I"> <span style="color: gray;">24m</span></div>
</div>
<a class="AB" href="https://zoro.to/steinsgate-3?ref=search">
    <div class="Queen">
        <div class="a">Steins Gate</div>
    <div class="b"><span style="color: rgb(168, 164, 164);">⭐9.09</span></div>
    <div class="c"><span style="color: rgb(168, 164, 164);">Ep24/24</span></div>
    <div class="ac"></div>
    <div class="d"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">TV</span></div>
    <div class="e"><span style="color: rgb(168, 164, 164);">The self-proclaimed mad scientist Rintarou
         Okabe rents out a room in a rickety old building in 
         Akihabara, where he indulges...</span>
        </div>
        
    </div>
   
       
</a>        


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please can you check the codepen link attachment.

Comment: Yes, I have checked and update my answer again

Comment: @RubelRana you can accept my answer, if you feel correct answer